# regular expression to check only one decimal point

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following regular expression to check only one decimal point for type number tag in html

```
^-?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*$
```

but this regular failed to check If I put decimal at the end  e.g `12.12.`
what further I have to add to check this

Comment: Are you parsing html with regex? `type number tag in html`

Comment: Try `^-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$`

Comment: I will check it and reply u shortly @wp78de

Answer (score 2):

I think your regex can be easily fixed using a `+` instead of last `*` quantifier:

```
^-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$
```

Tests:

```js
const regex = /^-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/gm;
console.log('regex.test?')
console.log('12 = ' + regex.test('12'));
console.log('12. = ' + regex.test('12.'));
console.log('12.1 = ' + regex.test('12.1'));
console.log('12.12. = ' + regex.test('12.12.'));
console.log('-1 = ' + regex.test('-1'));
console.log('-1. = ' + regex.test('-1.'));
console.log('-1.2 = ' + regex.test('-1.2'));
console.log('-.12 = ' + regex.test('-.12'));
console.log('-. = ' + regex.test('-.'));
console.log('-. = ' + regex.test('-'));
console.log('. = ' + regex.test('.'));
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8jnpRf/1)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below : `[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to allow a possible `.` at the end is to have `\.?` just before the `$`.  Also, the double `\` looks wrong (unless you need it for escaping a `\` in the context in which you are using it):

```
^-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*\.?$
```

But please recognize that your regex does not require any actual digits, so will match some non-numbers, like `.`, `-.` and (with my edit) `-..`  The above regex will also match an empty string!

You will want to either change your regex to require digits, or take into account somewhere else that they might not be there.